# Examples of MVVM adoption outside the Microsoft community?

Tags: web-development, javascript, design-patterns, mvvm

IS MVVM getting any kind of traction outside the Microsoft community?  Within Silverlight this is a non-issue, but for other technologies, like JavaScript it surely is:  For instance Knockout.js is a great framework, but the 'rest of the world' seems to be on a Backbone path.

My concern is that MVVM frameworks (like Knockout) are going to suffer a lack of network effect by being constrained to the Microsoft ecosystem, and thus fall behind compared to the rest.

Answer (score 5):

MVVM outside of the Microsoft is known by another name. [Presentation Model](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/PresentationModel.html). This appears to be gaining traction especially in the Flex world. I'm still learning the ropes but it seems to be gaining traction.

Various Flex examples I have found recently are:

1. [Cafe Townsend](https://github.com/swiz/swiz-examples)
2. [Score Keeper](http://riarockstars.com/2011/03/16/presentation-model-and-multiple-screens-part-1/)

One question that continues to bug me is when do you need a dedicated Controller in MVVM / Presentation Model. Some examples have dedicated controllers (e.g., Cafe Townsend) and others do not (e.g., Score Keeper).  However, I think this is a question for another post.

Comment: Isn't Presentation Model just MVVM v0.1?  It appears to be the creation of the same fertile Fowler mind...  But thanks for the Flex references.

Comment: AFAIK MVVM is the Presentation Model pattern applied specifically to WPF and Silverlight. There may be a little "special sauce" to make it work well with those specific technologies but the overall pattern is the same. View = View, Model = Model, ViewModel = Presentation Model.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MVVM) article, there are a dozen+ implementations of the MVVM framework. Given that [Mono](http://xamarin.com/) is out there as well, I'm not sure I'd use the word "constrained". So, no I don't think they'll be constrained as such. However, as pointed out in the same article, MVVM isn't always the best design choice.

Comment: Just because a project is open-source doesn't mean it is outside the Microsoft community.  The vast majority (if not all) of the projects listed in the WP entry are MS focused.  I'm not saying that being MS focused is bad, it just limits the audience.  One of the beautiful things about jQuery for instance is that it crosses the Java/LAMP/MS/Whatever boundaries that normally constrain frameworks.